# running total in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I'm having some issues in a unix shell script I'm trying to write that keeps a running total of the number of lines in multiple files from the command line.  I can count the lines individually and display them for each run through the loop but my lines variable always reads 0 at the end.

```
#! /bin/sh
lines=0

line_count(){
    #count the lines
    l= blablabla.....
    lines=`lines + l`
}

for f in "$@"
do
echo "total lines:"
( line_count "$f" )
done
```

Comment: What's wrong with `wc -l file`?

Comment: You just want `sh` or you don't have access to `wc`, How about `grep -c '.*'`

Comment: I have the script how I want it, I just don't understand this whole sub shell thing that I believe is the cause of my counter not keeping track like it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run something in a subshell, any variable changes you do (e.g. increasing `$lines`) are only valid within that subshell and are lost when the subshell exits. But since you are using a function you don't need a subshell at all, just call the function.

Also `` lines=`lines + l` `` will try to execute the command `lines` with arguments `+` and `l`, which I think is not what you intended. To evaluate the result of an expression, use the `$(( ... ))` syntax, and prepend `$` to your variables to work with their values.

Finally you never use the value of `$lines`, you may want to print it after you've called the function.

```bsh
#! /bin/sh
lines=0

line_count(){
    #count the lines
    l= blablabla.....
    lines=$(( $lines + $l ))
}

for f in "$@"
do
    line_count "$f"
    echo "total lines: $lines"
done
```

Comment: Would it be bad to just save the running total to a file and then grab the values out of there when I need them?  Is that bad practice?

Comment: @jimjohnjim, it can be done that way but it would be much more efficient to keep the data in memory, especially for cases like this where you store a single number. For more complex tasks it may be necessary or helpful to write partial results to file for use later.